# Hash symbol (#) not working

Tags: keyboard, shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, 18.04

I installed a fresh installation of Ubuntu Bbionic 18.04 LTS.

When I press key <kbd>3</kbd> I get "3" as output.

But When I press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>, the expected output is "#", but I get nothing.

More problems: Sometimes <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> also do not work.

**Edit 1:**

Using:

```
xev | grep -A2 --line-buffered '^KeyRelease' | sed -n '/keycode /s/^.*keycode \([0-9]*\).* (.*, \(.*\)).*$/\1 \2/p'
```

The output of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> is: `12 numbersign` (expected hash instead of numbersign)

The output of <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> is: `11 at` which is as expected.

Comment: Can you try another keyboard?

Comment: how to select another keyboard?

Comment: `Settings` > `Region and Language` make sure to select the right `Input Sources` for your keyboard

Comment: I meant another physical keyboard.

Comment: I use dual boot. In windows, it works perfect

Comment: On my 18.04 I can click on gear next to `Sign In` and select one of five Desktop environments. Which one are you using?

Answer (score 3):

Set *Settings* → *Region and Language* → *Input Sources* to *English (US)*.

I was facing the same problem when my *Input Sources* were set to *English (UK)*. After changing it to *English (US)*, the keyboard behavior was normal and I was getting "#" when <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd> was being pressed.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one it worked for me: <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>3</kbd>